# XSLT2.0 | Saxon HE | passing separator as param

Tags: xslt-2.0

Having function like this below:

```
<xsl:function name="fn:get-hierachy">

    <xsl:param name="hierarchy"   required="yes" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator0"  required="no"  as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$hierarchy/*" separator="$separator0"/>

</xsl:function>
```

I'm getting 'separator0' as a delimiter for output eg.

`<xsl:value-of select="fn:get-hierarchy($place, ' > ')"/>` result in:

`Earth$separator0Africa$separator0Egypt`

I'm passing my custom delimiter as a second function argument = `' > '` but it's being ignored and variable name is used instead.

Desired output:
`Earth > Africa > Egypt`

> **Is it possible to pass separator argument value as a parameter?**

Comment: You seem to have stumbled on a Saxon bug here: Saxon is ignoring `xsl:function/xsl:param[@required='no']`, when it should be rejecting it as an error. Function parameters are always required.

Comment: Bug now fixed, see: see https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2448 (Saxon will now report an error for your example function).

Comment: Thank you for information. Although @Martin Honnen provided working workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `separator` attribute, you need to use an attribute value template `<xsl:value-of select="$hierarchy/*" separator="{$separator0}"/>`.